# Invalid function signature when loading Rust-generated webassembly binary from Python

Tags: javascript, python, rust, webassembly

The full code is here:

https://github.com/dmerejkowsky/chuck-norris-webassembly-plugins

Here's what's wrong

There's a `get_fact` method written in Rust and exported with `wasm_bindgen`:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_fact() -> String {
    "Chuck Norris can slam a revolving door".to_string()
}
```

When I build the `wasm` file with `wasm-pack --target nodejs` I can call the `get_fact` just fine from Javascript:

```js
const assert = require('node:assert/strict');
const ck = require('../pkg/chuck_norris.js');

const actual = ck.get_fact();
assert.ok(actual.includes("Chuck Norris"));
```

But when trying to write the same test in Python:

```py
from wasmer import engine, Store, Module, Instance
from wasmer_compiler_cranelift import Compiler

rust_wasm = Path / "to" / "chucknorris_bg.wasm"

store = Store(engine.Universal(Compiler))
module = Module(store, rust_wasm.read_bytes())
instance = Instance(module)
get_fact = instance.exports.get_fact
actual = get_fact()
assert "Chuck Norris" in actual
```

I get :

```
RuntimeError: Parameters of type [] did not match signature [I32] -> []
```

Any clues as to why NodeJs and Python disagree on the signature of the `get_fact()` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself: you *cannot* use webassembly with strings this way. More info on this blog post: https://medium.com/wasm/strings-in-webassembly-wasm-57a05c1ea333